# Como esperar pelo resultado de uma consulta no Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, typescript, angular, firebase-database

Meu problema é o seguinte:

Eu tenho um componente que irá listar umas categorias, exemplo:

```
categories: Observable<any[]>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = this.categoryService.getAll();
}
```

No service eu preciso fazer uma consulta primeiro no usuário (para obter um atributo dele), para só depois consultar as categorias. Exemplo:

```
getAll() {
  this.userService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(user => {
    this.partnership_id = user.partnership_id;
    this.categories = this.db.colWithIds$<Category>('categories', ref => ref
      .where('partnership_id', '==', this.partnership_id)
      .where('enable', '==', true)
      .orderBy('name')
    );
  });
  return this.categories;
}
```

Só que dessa forma, retorna as categorias em branco, pois o return executa primeiro que a consulta no firestore.

Como proceder nesse caso?

Comment: O valor so esta disponível dentro do subscribe mesmo pq e assincriono. você pode colocar um loading ate a query retornar ou usar o async pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore é uma promise, ou seja, você precisa passar uma função de callback no "getAll" e no final de todo o processo, já quando estiver com as categorias então chamar a função passada com o resultado.

```
function petecas(categorias) {
    console.log(categorias);
}

getAll(petecas);

function getAll(petecas) {
      this.userService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(user => {
        this.partnership_id = user.partnership_id;
        this.categories = this.db.colWithIds$<Category>('categories', ref => ref
          .where('partnership_id', '==', this.partnership_id)
          .where('enable', '==', true)
          .orderBy('name')
        );
        petecas(this.categories);
      });
      /*return this.categories;*/
    }
```